# Changing tyres on Giant Defy road bike

Tags: tire

Is it possible to change from road tyres to commuter tyres on a [2014 Giant Defy](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/nz/defy-composite-3-2014)?
Thanks

Comment: Changing tires is relatively easy, so long as the size of the new tires suits the existing rim and frame clearance.

Comment: Question title needs an update, its about tyres not wheels

Comment: @AndyP You have enough reputation to unilaterally make the edit. Just Do It.™

Answer (score 7):

That model of Giant Defy will have clearance for almost any 700×28 tyres and some 700×30 models, but not all. If you are after a commuter tyre for increased puncture resistance, a Schwalbe Durano plus in 700×28 will be as good as any of the wider commuter tyres and will perform just as well on any sealed surfaces. If you want to ride a bigger tyre for better grip on gravel and unsealed roads, then your options are very limited.

Comment: Short of MTB trails or roads surfaced with loose broken stone you can ride pretty much any road or bike path on 28s. If it is a little rough I'd want something a bit tougher as well as a little more grip - but only something like marathon plus. Even with 28s you'll struggle to get mudguards in there, and they're good to have commuting in imperfect conditions

Comment: I'll note that 28s can be a bit iffy on the rear wheel if you're loading up the rear panniers on that road bike commuter with 10-15 kg or 20-30 lbs of stuff.  If you're going to load a bike like that, you really do need larger tires, especially on the rear.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That depends how much you weigh ;)  I could load 20kg extra over the rear wheel and it wouldn't be any different to a larger bloke riding the bike unloaded.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I run marathon plus 28 on the back of a hybrid with a ~20kg passenger in a ~3kg seat, and I'm over 80kg myself.  You've got to pump them up quite hard though. It looks like durano are rated to a high enough pressure as well.

Comment: @ChrisH And you're real careful that you don't hit pavement edges square on at speed with that, aren't you?  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I definitely don't ride up or down kerbs with my daughter on the back, and do a decent job of avoiding potholes at all times (more so with her on the back, being a little slower and more wary).  But I can hit low hard edges like badly dropped kerbs with no trouble.  The one pinch flat I've had was on a 32mm marathon supreme pumped up hard - and a very sharp-edged pothole